# Python, optimizing a list comprehension for string concatenation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, list-comprehension

I'm using `cProfile` to run benchmarks on a script that process strings via list comprehension. The target line I'd like to optimize looks like this:

```
signals = [('prefix' + str(day) + '_' + s) for s in signals]
```

where `day` is an integer.

This particular line is using a whopping 33% of the entire run time. Of course, it's called million of times during the execution.

I've tried a couple obvious alternatives, including `''.join('prefix', str(day), '_', s)`, `'prefix{:}_'.format(day)`, and using `numpy.core.defchararray.add` to concatenate a prefix array created via `numpy.tile` with `signals`. They are both up to 2x slower than list comprehension.

Is there still room for speed optimization for this line?

Comment: can you specify what is `s`?

Comment: `s` is a string with length in range 4 to 32

Comment: Do you need a list? I made the experience that using a generator as often as possible instead often brings a speedup.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes because eventually this list has to be serialized and sent to another module.

Comment: How much time is the serialization taking?

Comment: Well, serialization is not the culprit at the moment. I've already used the best possible solution: `'\t'.join(strings)`, and it's much faster than anything else.

Comment: Do you need the list, or just the serialization? Because `prefix = 'prefix' + str(day) + '_'; result = prefix + ('\t'+prefix).join(signals)` could produce the serialization directly in a much quicker manner than going through the list.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll definitely do some research together on serialization to see if anything can be done there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should bring at least a minimum improvement:

```
# First precalculate the static part of the string
template = 'prefix%s_' % day + '%s'

# Then, use the %s string interpolation instead of joining strings with '+'  
# -->> Note: this proved to be wrong later... 
signals = [template % s for s in signals]

# Alternatively you could use map to compare efficiency (be aware of differences between python 2 and 3)
signals = map(template.__mod__, signals)
```

The `str.format` is more expensive than the `%s` interpolation, so I am not going to try it.

Now let's compare the timings. Your method:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> day = 45
>>> signals = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccccc', 'dddddddddddd']
>>> timeit.timeit("[('prefix' + str(day) + '_' + s) for s in signals]", 'from __main__ import day, signals')
1.35095184709592
```

My first approach

```
>>> template = 'prefix%s_' % day + '%s'
>>> timeit.timeit("[template % s for s in signals]", 'from __main__ import template, signals')
0.7075940089748229
```

My second approach

```
>>> timeit.timeit("map(template.__mod__, signals)", 'from __main__ import template, signals')
0.9939713030159822
```

So, the precalculation of the template with list comprehension seems to win. There are further things to consider, as for example, if a generator is good enough for you.

**EDIT** from info pointed out in the interesing comments, I add another solution: inside of the tight loop we are only joining two strings together, so we can concatenate them directly instead of %-formatting

```
>>> template = 'prefix%s_' % day
>>> timeit.timeit("[template + s for s in signals]", 'from __main__ import template, signals')
0.39771016975851126
```

Which for the moment is the winner.

Comment: String concatenation is only O(n^2) when you're concatenating n strings together. n independent concatenations of pairs of 2 strings is more efficient than n independent uses of % formatting.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I have implemented pre-calculation, though still with str concatenation instead of formatting (which is slower). It's faster but I wish I could do something to the list comprehension itself.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right, to join only two strings it is more efficient to concatenate them instead of % formatting. I updated the answer with timing and it is a big improvement.

Comment: @HeShiming have you considered using a generator instead of a list? I dont know what you intend to do with the list, but maybe that can bring further improvements

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried:

```
signals = ['prefix{0}_{1}'.format(day, s) for s in signals]
```

As a baseline, what if you just used a tuple instead of a string?:

```
signals = [(day, s) for s in signals]
```

Comment: Yes, it's similar to my original solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be faster

```py
import numpy as np
signal = [x for x in range(9000)]
length = len(signal) 
prefArray = np.array(['prefix']*length )
dArray = np.array([str(day)]*length )
cArray = np.array(['_']*length )
sArray = np.array(["%s"%x for x in signal])

firstArray = np.core.defchararray.add(prefArray, dArray)
secondArray = np.core.defchararray.add(cArray, sArray)
result = np.core.defchararray.add(firstArray,secondArray)
print result
```